# Firebase REST api streaming issue

Tags: rest, streaming, firebase

When the Accept-header is set to "text/event-stream", it receive timeout error. I've tried it on REST-Console(Chrome Store) and Unity3D which give me a never ending freeze.

source : https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-03-24-streaming-for-firebase-rest-api.html

Comment: What is the request you access?

Comment: I don't think anybody can help you here without seeing the error and sufficient description that we could try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: So I briefly describe what I have done. I uses get method to send the URL with auth parameter included, I can receive the data just like what it should be. For what I understand from the sources webpage, I have to set the accept-header to "text/event-stream" in order to start call the streaming feature, instead of that I got atimeout error.

Comment: @user3373752: 1) Are you behind proxy? 2) try using curl request from console.